# Oracle Apex Master Detail Report and Detail report with Radio Button Option to select

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am looking for advice to build a simple Quiz type application in Oracle Apex.
I don't need to build any Create/Update/Delete screens for base tables since I will populate my tables with data using SQL statements.

I have two tables

```
Create Table Question_Bank
(
Question_Id              Number (5)   Primary Key ,
Question_Description     Varchar2(1000)
)
;
```

Question_Choice_Id is like 1,2,3,4 ( it is like no of quiz option choices)

```
Create Table  Question_Choices
(
Question_Choice_Pk            Number (5)   Primary Key,
Question_Id                   Number(5) References Question_Bank(Question_Id),
Question_Choice_Id            Number(1),
Question_Choice_Description   Varchar2(200),
Is_Correct                    Varchar(1) Default 'N',
Explanation                   Varchar2(500)
);
```

So application should be displaying questions and options like this.
I would prefer one scrollable page of some numbers on question on one page.

```
This is Question No 1

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4


This is Question No 2

Another Option 1
Another Option 2
Another Option 3
Another Option 4


This is Question No 3

Q No 3  Option 1
Q No 3  Option 2
Q No 3  Option 3
Q No 3  Option 4
```

So far I have created Master/Detail form which is kind of report (not editable) and I can see questions and possible choices (I have select question and choices are shown in 2nd column) but this is not what I want.
I am using Free Oracle Apex online account version 20.2.

Comment: If you need sql file for Table and data, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZGTNr5RnHpT_ljllTuaVteFoZ4VAjNws/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How page should look https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rUCpakgwYeSp8zzKH-V813P0-9sIQii6gEO-CAKZpBI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try dynamicly build page with questions and choices. You have to add a new `PL/SQL Dynamic Region` region to page. In `Source > PL/SQL Code` region attribute put sample code below.

```
FOR l_question IN (
    SELECT QUESTION_ID, QUESTION_DESCRIPTION
    FROM QUESTION_BANK
    order by QUESTION_ID
) LOOP
    HTP.P('<h3>' || APEX_ESCAPE.HTML(l_question.QUESTION_DESCRIPTION) || '</h3>');
    HTP.P(
        APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(
            p_idx   => 1, -- Values stored in APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01 table.
            p_value => l_question.QUESTION_ID
        )
    );
    HTP.P('<fieldset id="qfs' || l_question.QUESTION_ID || '">');
    HTP.P(
        APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
            p_idx           => 2, -- Values stored in APEX_APPLICATION.g_f02 table.
            p_item_id       => 'qh' || l_question.QUESTION_ID,
            p_attributes    => 'style="display:none"'
        )
    );
    
    FOR l_choice IN (
        SELECT QUESTION_CHOICE_ID, QUESTION_CHOICE_DESCRIPTION
        FROM QUESTION_CHOICES
        WHERE QUESTION_ID = l_question.QUESTION_ID
    ) LOOP
        HTP.P('<input type="radio" value="' || l_choice.QUESTION_CHOICE_ID || '" name="' || l_question.QUESTION_ID || '" onchange="document.getElementById(''qh' || l_question.QUESTION_ID || ''').value = this.value">');
        HTP.P('<label for="' || l_question.QUESTION_ID || '">' || APEX_ESCAPE.HTML(l_choice.QUESTION_CHOICE_DESCRIPTION) || '</label>');
    END LOOP;
    
    HTP.P('</fieldset>');
END LOOP;
```

This PL/SQL block iterates through all questions, then prints HTML markup with question description and fieldset with radio buttons. As you can see I use `APEX_ITEM` package to generate two columns - `QUESTION_ID` and `QUESTION_CHOICE_ID`. Each iteration creates new record with these two columns. If you checked the APEX documentation you may wonder why I didn't use `APEX_ITEM.RADIOGROUP` for building radio buttons. The trick is this procedure doesn't fit for this case, because its behaves different then developers expects. So insted of using this procedure i build radio group buttons manually. I also put simple `onchange` event for every `input` to save selected choice in every question. This event sets item in second column.

Each column is stored in collection `APEX_APPLICATION.G_Fxx`, where `xx` is between `01` and `50`. There is `p_idx` parameter which determines index of collection for store column values. After page submit, APEX submit values in those collections. You can handle this, creating new process (`Processing > Processes` or `Processing > After Submit`) and pasting code below.

```
DECLARE
    v_question_count    NUMBER := APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01.COUNT;
    v_question_answer_id QUESTION_ANSWERS.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID%TYPE := QUESTION_ANSWERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..v_question_count LOOP
        INSERT INTO QUESTION_ANSWERS (QUESTION_ANSWER_ID, QUESTION_ID, QUESTION_CHOICE_ID)
        VALUES (v_question_answer_id, APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01(i), APEX_APPLICATION.g_f02(i));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

There is another iteration through collections (both has the same number of members) and insert values into some table.

My code generates form without fancy styling, so you have to handle this yourself :)

Comment: Thanks Damian. You are Apex genius. I have asked same question in Oracle community but did not get proper answer. You code is displaying as it supposed to. I have only basic knowledge of Apex so still trying to understand. Can you please explain what is  p_idx   => 1, -- Values stored in APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01 table. and p_idx=>2.  Isn't in loop iteration, it would be again p_idx=>1 and what is p_item_id       => 'qh' . It is just amazing how easily you have put this page.

Comment: In First Loop of Question_Bank, I see that Hidden Item is created to store Question_Id in APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01 collection.   HTP.P(
        APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
            p_idx           => 2, -- Values stored in APEX_APPLICATION.g_f02 table.
            p_item_id       => 'qh' || l_question.QUESTION_ID,
            p_attributes    => 'style="display:none"'
        )
    );
    
    Here again you are adding apex_item.text with 2nd collection but again question_Id is getting stored. Is this correct ? Is it supposed to be Question_Choice_Id and if so then it should be in 2nd loop inside.

Comment: `p_idx` parameter is for specify index of target `APEX_APPLICATION.g_fxx` collection. If `p_idx = 1` then APEX creates new member in `APEX_APPLICATION.g_f01` collection. If `p_idx = 2` then creates new member in `APEX_APPLICATION.g_f02` etc. In yout case you need to create "virtual" table with two columns - quiestion_id and question_choice_id. To do so i put two `APEX_ITEM` calls in each iteration. One `APEX_ITEM` is stored in first collection, and second `APEX_ITEM` is stored in second collection.

Comment: `p_item_id` parameter is for setting HTML `id` attribute of new item. I do so, because I need to set specific `id` for every hidden item, which stores a selected choice in a specific question. I use this `id` in JavaScript code in `onchange` event of every `input` element. In this event browser sets target hidden item. As a selector I use value of `id` attribute.

Comment: In the first loop, the first item stores `QUESTION_ID`, but the second stores NULL (because I didn't set `p_value` parameter). I as mentioned before, the second item is for storing selected choice. When APEX renders your quiz user didn't select any choice yet, so this is why the second item is NULL by default. To set this item I use `onchange` event.

Comment: Thanks Damian. It is working as expected. I need to enhance little bit like adding validation that user select some choice for every question. Will this go in after submit ?

Comment: I think it will be better when you put your validation in `Processing > Validation`. In `Processing > After Submit`  you put process which has to be done before page validations.

Comment: Thanks @Damian for your help. I have one more question, I have made a page item Max Questions to Display as an item on page and put some default number as well and this is user input field. I have used this item variable to Dynamic Content but issue is that only default works, if we change it on screen, Dynamic Content does not use value entered since I see same number of questions. Is it possible or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: No problem:)
You have to submit that item (e.g. by a new page button). PL/SQL Dynamic region reads value of that item from session state. After submit, your page will be reloaded. You also have to set `Server Side Condition` on page process, which handles user choices. It will be necessary, to prevent executing that process by your new "filter" button.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the *Survey Builder* app, which allows users to review/preview/submit questions and answers.
This application can solve the requirement you have or give you an idea on how to build it.

You can find this application at *App Gallery*.
[image: Survey Builder app]

Comment: Thanks Monica. I did look into Survey app but somehow, I was not able to make it work for my requirement.